# When opening website, index.html doesn't automatically open?

Tags: html

When going to my website, qlite-usa.com, index.html does not load. I get an error message on the main page. But if I go to qlite-usa.com/index.html, the website loads just fine.

How do I make it so qlite-usa.com automatically sends me to qlite-usa.com/index.html?

I've tried changing index.html to home.html and others, none of that worked.

I use godaddy.

Comment: This has to do with how the server is set up; do you have control over that?

Comment: That's a server config issue.

Comment: This question belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a server configuration issue. If it is allowed by your host, try creating a file in your root directory named: `.htaccess` (yes, it is a file with no name, just an extension). Inside this file, save the following content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: This is amazing. I can now rename the `index.html` to anything, yay! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you told us what company you use for hosting we might be able to do research to see what the server uses as the default homepage.

90% of the time it's index, but it can be other things, like default.html. Also, maybe try the extension .htm vs .html. It will make a difference.